# Loading a custom template in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

Following [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278817/creating-a-default-preamble) on my previous question about creating a default preamble, I tried to create a custom template in TexStudio using the commands `file`-->`make template`.

Even though the template is saved in .config/template subfolder (I am using Ubuntu 14.04), I cannot load it by using the commands `file`-->`new from template`.

In other words, TexStudio finds only default templates (article, book, koma-script, etc).

So my question is how to say to TexStudio to load my custom template?

Comment: I have no problems with this (in Linux Mint if that matter). The user templates are stored in  `~/.config/texstudio/templates/user` and should be one `template_yourtemplate.tex` and one `template_yourtemplate.json`.

Comment: In that folder I have one file `template_yourtemplate.json` and another `template_yourtemplate.sty`. I don't know if `.sty` causes the problem. I will try to convert it in `.tex` file

Comment: Ok! The problem is solved. As it proved, `.sty` format caused the problem.

Comment: while this may work for you, there is a significant difference between `.sty` and `.tex` files that may cause problems for someone else.  if a file contains any command name in which an `@` sign appears, the `.sty` file will automatically recognize it, but in a `.tex` file, the affected code must be surrounded by `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` to be handled properly.  so, in general, `.tex` and `.sty` files are *not* interchangeable.

Comment: As I understand TeXstudio templates, as stated there needs to be 2 files placed into ~/.config/texstudio/templates/user, your_template.json (defines author, date, and files to open) and your_template.zip (which contains the tex files to be opened when creating).

Answer (score 0):

After you save the template in File > Make Template... with information like Name, Author, Version, Description and License, you select the option File > New From Template... With that, it will open a Select LaTeX Template tab. So, just choose the custom template you saved in User.
Now if your question is how to do this by command, I don't know the answer. Also, I don't know if this option is compatible with other versions of TeXstudio. The one I have is 2.12.6.

Comment: As you may read in my description, the problem (for me) was that I could not access my saved template, because for some reason TeXStudio could not recognise .sty format. Once I converted to a .tex file, then your solution worked