# Best way to reuse and change code in a lot of documents

Tags: code

I would like to use in a lot of documents the same title page and some settings in a way that when I want to implement a change to take effect in all of them.

One way that I thought is to place everything in a `newcommand` having as an option the name of the document. But I don't think that this is the best way, as the code is quite a lot and it seems somewhat "wrong".

So my question is what is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Related/duplicate? [Creating a default preamble](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278817). It sounds like this is a good use case for a package or document class.

Comment: @AlanMunn I have a default preamble that I use generally. I only want a specific part of the code. Also in every document there is a new title so even with the preamble I can't control that. Furthermore my question has a main topic what is the best way to implement what I am asking (i.e. something of a comparison). Thank you for the recommendation though.

Comment: if you look at my answer to the linked question, I'm not a big fan of default preambles... But it looks like you could make what you want to do a package or class.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes I am reading it now. It is helpful.

Comment: Perhaps then here is a better source of information: [How do I create a LaTeX package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34175)