# Combining everything before begin document into a package

Tags: document-classes

sorry if the title is badly worded but I wasn't sure how to word it.

My question is this: I have a lot of things before  `\begin{document}` in my latex file, maybe like 180 lines of setting up commands and use packages.

I was wondering if I could put all the code above the line `\begin{document}` into a package and import that in so I can save lines.

Thanks

Comment: For a single document, you can just save all the files as e.g. `mypreamble.tex` and then use `\input{mypreamble}`.  No real need to make a package.

Comment: @AlanMunn A project specific preamble and a default preamble are different things.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Of course, but the principles of creating the package are identical.

Comment: @AlanMunn Not entirely. For a project I would rather use a class instead of a package, because I have then a really clean preamble for the document.

Comment: Could you also put the `\bibliographystyle` in there as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a class:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{MyProject}[2018/03/10 v1.0 Class for my project]
\LoadClass[<options>]{<class name>}% former: \documentclass[...]{...}

\RequirePackage[<options>]{<package name>}% former: \usepackage[...]{...}

% other stuff from the preamble

\endinput
```

`\documentclass` and `\usepackage` need other names, see above.
Also, remove `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` pairs, because `\makeatletter` is automatically active in class and package files.

Then use the class:

```
\documentclass{MyProject}
\begin{document}
  ...
\end{document}
```

A class or package have advantages over a simple `\input`:

- Options can be added.
- Some version support by LaTeX:

  ```
  \documentclass{<class>}[2018/03/10]
  \usepackage{<package>}[2018/03/10]
  ```

  Then, LaTeX will warn, if the class or package are older than specified.