# Pros and cons using \usepackage and \input used for preamble

Tags: packages

Recently, I found a question on how to use preamble kind of thing that we can use for storing the name of the style files and personal macros. I generally use `\input{preamble.tex}`. What is the pros and cons if I use `\usepackage{preamble}`?

Comment: Try `\input{tikz.sty}\begin{document}Hello!\end{document}`. A lot of funny errors appear. As far as I know, `\usepackage` or actually `\RequirePackage` does a lot of processing before loading a `.sty` file and a lot of macro/catcode juggling too. It also cares about versioning, package options... `\input` just load a file and smiles a "Good luck" to you.

Comment: `\input` is really easy to manage, you just do whatever you would've done in your preamble in that file and use `\input{foo}`. A `\usepackage` shouldn't use `\usepackage` but `\RequirePackage` for any other packages it needs, and it should report back who it is with `\ProvidesPackage`. A `\usepackage` will automatically have `\makeatletter` at its start and `\makeatother` at its end. Else the two are roughly the same.

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz Can you turn your comment into a response?

Comment: Related: [Creating a default preamble](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/278817)

Comment: it should be noted that MikTeX maintains its own database of sty files and will not recognize a sty tile until it is added to the FNDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\input` macro essentially is the same as putting the contents of the input file where the macro is used. So to use it is really easy, you can use anything you would use in your preamble in that file and input it.

Creating a file to be input by `\usepackage` is a bit more complicated (but not that much). First a file input with `\usepackage` should report which file that is using `\ProvidesPackage` (optionally with specifying a date, version, and purpose). Also, a package shouldn't include additional packages with `\usepackage`, but instead use `\RequirePackage`. Inside a package you don't have to use `\makeatletter` at the start and `\makeatother` at its end.

Other than that, the two are roughly the same and there isn't too much difference (from a technical viewpoint, conceptually there is a difference, see the [link Alan Munn provided](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278817)).

Comment: note that _by design_ packages may use `\usepackage` and `\ProvidesPackage`  is optional, so the intention is that it is _easier_ to use `\usepackage` (as the catcode of `@` is managed automatically)

Comment: So, it appears that \usepackage ignores the packages that are not required for a certain case, however \input always loads the all packages listed in the preamble.tex. Am I correct?

Comment: @user199 no, `\RequirePackage` will also load packages. The difference is that `\RequirePackage` can be used before a `\documentclass`, while `\usepackage` can't, else the two *do* the same, that is again a conceptual difference.