# How to import a list of packages from another folder?

Tags: packages

Usually to import packages we do

```
\usepackage{a}
...
\usepackage{z}
```

what if I wanted to define a file containing the package names

```
./myPackages.tex

a,b, ... ,z
```

How can I import this file into my main LaTeX file. I have tried `\usepackage{\input{myPackages}}` and this did not work.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278817/creating-a-default-preamble/278818#278818

Comment: that is have the file be a list of `\usepackage` not a list of package names,