# How to create your own class for a very specific usage?

Tags: packages, document-classes, package-writing, documentclass-writing

I have created my resume in Latex and honestly, I like it a lot. I was thinking of making a template and publish it somewhere so that people can use it. But it's rather complicated and it would be best if I created a class or package of some sort. The resume uses `article` class and it just has a bunch of modification and styles (mentioning it in case it's necessary).

It would basically create new commands so that the usage in the file itself is cleaner. I now have all those commands (the ones I've defined so far at least) in another `.tex` called preamble. But if I want someone to use these commands as a template, in what kind of file should they be stored? Are the definitions with `\newcommand` usable at all for what I intend? Or is it only possible to use them if I keep the preamble `.tex`?

Found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53388/customizing-latex-create-a-document-class-or-a-package) and it seems that creating a new document class would be best. Would that be your suggestion as well? Do you know of any tutorials to introduce the creation of a document class?

Or should I be doing something else entirely?

Thank you!

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing the code and how extensive it is. If it is closely tied to but modifies the `resume` class then it is probably better to make it a `cls` file but if it could be used with other document classes then make it a `sty` file.

Comment: It doesn't use resume class (didn't even know it existed), just a regular `article` class with modifications to the background and `section` environment, it also uses `minipage`, `tcolorbox` and `descriptions`
 a lot.

Comment: ...sorry I meant the `article` class...

Comment: Thank you! I will look into how to make a `.cls`.

Comment: If you decide to release your work, please choose a unique and searchable/googleable name (there are too many classes out there called `thesis` or `resume` or `cv` already). Add clear version information so that people know which version they are using. I personally also think that there comes a certain amount of responsibility with releasing one's work: Ideally you should be prepared to maintain and support your work for the time to come. Document your work, ideally with a user-level documentation in PDF form.

Comment: For thesis or CV templates it might make sense to provide several files: One `.cls` or `.sty` file that contains the gory details of the implementation and should *not* be touched by users, one `.tex` file that shows in great detail how the class/package can be used and maybe an additional shorter `.tex` file that people can use as base for their work (of course it can make sense to combine the two `.tex` files and the larger `.tex` file should not be a substitute for a proper documentation).

Comment: I will keep that in mind and make everything as self explanatory as it can be.